# Get size of uncompressed file based on the db column size which is compressed using System.IO.Ionic.Zlib.DotNetZip.dll

Tags: c#, zlib

Using Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream I am creating and compressing the xml file content and storing it in db in db column fileDetails.
And when user downloads the file I am uncompressing it using ZlibStream.
I need to get the size of the uncompressed file based on the db column fileDetails content size.
Is there any formula to get size of uncompressed file based on the db column size?

I am using constructor of to compress or de-compress file

> `public ZlibStream(Stream stream, CompressionMode mode);`

Comment: You could use the TotalOut property - but only after having read the whole stream.

Comment: I am looking for something in which I can get this result using dbquery only. Something like formula

Comment: I fear there is no closed formula for this. If you still can change the DB schema, you could add another column for the uncompressed size.

Comment: Why do you need the original file size and why don't you just save the original file size in the same db row. I also think that there can be a generell formular. For Example the strings `000000` and `123456` will have different ratios.